# Change class names with a mask? (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, object, addclass

The question is about jQuery.

What's the best way to find all classess that look like `superclass-XXXXX`, where `XXXXX` is a number (any integer one) on the page to change every such class to be `superclass-XXXXX-finished`?

For example, if there are `superclass-12345` and `superclass-34` classes on the page, they become `superclass-12345-finished` and `superclass-34-finished`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
function f() {
    $("[class]").each(function() {
        this.className = this.className.replace(/(super-\d+)(-finished)?/, function(a, b, c) {
            if (c == "") {
                return a + "-finished";
            }
            return a;
        });
    });
}


f();
f();
f();

console.log($("[class]").map(function() {
    return this.className;
}));
```

This will replace *every* occurance of `super-<some digits>` to `super-<same digits>-finished`, even if you have many such classes on a single element.

Input:

```
<div class="super-11"></div>
<div class="super-not-11"></div>
<div class="yes-super-111"></div>
```

Output:

```
<div class="super-11-finished"></div>
<div class="super-not-11"></div>
<div class="yes-super-111-finished"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9RFn4/1

Edit: Updated to filter out classes which end with `-finished`.

Comment: Seems like it wokrs. The only problem I've found is:
super-11 becomes super-11-finished (perfect!) and on the same event in a while it becomes super-11-finished. Is there any option to prevent that thing? I belive /super-(\d+)/ should be changed so it finds it only once. Thanks a lot anyway!!!

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo: super-11 -> super-11-finished -> super-11-finished-finished -> super-11-finished-finished-finished ...

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. The only thing I replaced your if (c == "") with if (typeof c == 'undefined'). It didn't go through this way of verification in my case. 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Find all of them starting with superclass like this:

```
$('*[class^="superclass"]')
```

Then change all classes that start with superclass, to a new class name:

```
$('*[class^="superclass"]').attr('class', 'newClass');
```

Comment: That won't match elements with multiple classes, unless the `superclass-XXXXX` class is the first one specified in the HTML. Not sure if handling elements with multiple classes is a requirement, but it's something to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your elements have just a single class of `superclass-*` :

```
$('*[class^="superclass"]').prop('class', $(this).prop('class') + '-finished');
```